# Why this prepare segue is not working?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard, segue

When i click the tableview i want to send the currentbook details to  another viewcontroller "detailpage"  and here its not sending any value?? why also it shows error?[image]

error : unknown receiver "tableview"

Comment: If you're initiating this segue from a click on a table view cell, then "sender" will be the cell, so you can get the indexPath with indexPathForCell:. No need to get a reference to the table at all.

Comment: Beyond rdelmar's observation, you're grabbing `indexPathForSelectedRow`, which returns a `NSIndexPath` and then calling `objectAtIndex` for that. You could just grab `row`. (So, rather than `[[[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] objectAtIndex:0] row]` you can just `[[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]`.) And if the `tableView` has an `IBOutlet` (or if you're using a `UITableViewController`), the common syntax would be `self.tableView`, not just `tableView` (though it depends upon how you've set up your tableview, something you haven't shared with us).

Answer (score -1):

Why are you creating two GMMDetailPage Objects? Also, you should most likely have `self.tableView` instead of just tableView. It would also be better to pass the tableView into the `prepareForSegues:sender:` method like so:

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath                             {

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bookItem" sender:tableView];
}`

Comment: (a) He's not creating two objects (though he is, admittedly, creating a redundant `GMMDetailpage` pointer, but that's very different than creating two objects); (b) If he's using cell prototypes, it `obviates` the need for this `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`; (c) this `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` doesn't nothing to solve his problem with his `prepareForSegue`.